# What free software can convert fillable forms pdf to fillable and **savable** pdf?

Tags: pdf, forms

There are files with fillable but not savable forms. Acrobat Reader does not allow save such documents.

What free software can convert fillable forms pdf to fillable and **savable** forms pdf?

Comment: Do you want to save a fillable form that you have filled in, or do you want to create a **new** fillable form?

Answer (score 5):

[This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/333081) on the Adobe forums indicates that there is no such free software. You'd have to buy Adobe Acrobat, and use LiveCycle Designer, which is included in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) was able to save the information of a form in a pdf.

Comment: May be it is my bad englsih. I do not want to save information of a form. I want to convert my document to be able to save these forms in Arcobat Reader.

Comment: @Alexey Malistov: No no, I just got it wrong, sorry. As far as I know, this is only possible with the professional version of the Reader: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can print these filled forms, you could use a [virtual printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software) to create a PDF file.

Comment: You did not understand my question. May be it is my bad english. I do not need change forms. I want to create pdf-document to other users (3rd party users) can save form changes. **Other users** have no virtual printers. They have only Acrobat Reader. I must create pdf with fillable and savable forms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any free ones which have worked as claimed. I found PDFill to be a great tool for working with PDFs. PDFill has some free tools, but the ability to create forms is not free. It is very inexpensive compared to alternatives. There might be a free trial. Check out their web site to see if it will work for you.

[PDFill Website](http://www.pdfill.com/)