# PDF - What software to fill-out/fill-in a PDF form?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What free software can convert fillable forms pdf to fillable and **savable** pdf?](https://superuser.com/questions/132510/what-free-software-can-convert-fillable-forms-pdf-to-fillable-and-savable-pd)

I need to fill-out a form, but I don't want to use an online service as the form contains personal information. I'm looking for a free software solution. The only free solutions I've found are essentially overlaying text on a screenshot of the pdf.

Comment: Print it off, fill it out, scan it back in.  I don't think you're going to find a free solution that isn't using an online service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)? It's a free app that I've used to fill out PDF forms and save them. Just be careful that you get the right version. This company has a number of other paid pdf products. It can even be used for commercial purposes without paying for a full license.

Answer (score 3):

Foxit Reader (free) can both fill out pre-made fill-able PDF forms, & also can use the typewriter function to write on an existing (non-fill-able) forms, & save same - without watermark.

"Foxit Reader 4.3"
http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/addons.php

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't able to go with the paid Adobe Acrobat solution, you should check out CutePDF. http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp its freeware for non commercial use only.

Comment: My version of CUTE doesn't offer a way to add information to a .pdf document.

Comment: I don't use fill-out pdfs often enough to justify spending any money on it. I have a feeling there aren't any free solutions because of adobe licensing/patents over pdfs. In the interim I'm using Adobe Fireworks to modify the doc

Comment: @Xavierjazz Apparently its only able to generate a PDF from an html page. Instructions: File->Print->Select CutePDF as printer... I can't fill-in pdfs with it.

Answer (score 1):

If a PDF has fields designated as input forms, you can use Adobe Acrobat Reader to type in the fields. Once done typing you could print it and re-scan it.

Comment: I'm using a free version of Adobe Reader 9. It focuses on the text fields, but I'm unable to edit/fill-out.