# How to save entered data in PDF

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF - What software to fill-out/fill-in a PDF form?](https://superuser.com/questions/281227/pdf-what-software-to-fill-out-fill-in-a-pdf-form)
>   [What free software can convert fillable forms pdf to fillable and **savable** pdf?](https://superuser.com/questions/132510/what-free-software-can-convert-fillable-forms-pdf-to-fillable-and-savable-pd)

I have a fillable pdf file. I can fill it but can't save.

Can I make it saveable pdf? Is there free software to make it saveable?

It says:

> Please fill out the following form. you cannot save data typed into
>   this form. Please print your completed form if you would like a copy
>   for your records.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill in all the fields then "print" it to a new PDF document with PDFCreator. The new PDF it generates won't be a fillable form anymore though.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/